# Calling stored procedure from job does nothing

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jobs

I have very simple stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FillMissingBirthDateFromMemberNumber
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Members
    SET BirthDate =
        CASE 
            WHEN CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(m.MemberNumber, 0, 7), 12) > '2030-01-01' 
            THEN dbo.fn_LocalTimeToUTC(DATEADD(YEAR, -100, CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(m.MemberNumber, 0, 7), 12)))
            ELSE dbo.fn_LocalTimeToUTC(CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(m.MemberNumber, 0, 7), 12))
        END 
    FROM Members m
    WHERE 
        m.BirthDate IS NULL AND
        m.MemberNumber IS NOT NULL AND
        m.MemberStatus IN (1,2)
END
```

that when executed in a query window, performs exactly as promised. It fills out missing birth dates based on the first six chars of the member number (with some caveats, as the `CASE WHEN` indicates).

Now, I have created a SQL job that simply `EXEC`s this stored procedure and reports success when run.
Only: nothing happens.

Also when I paste the code from the SP into the `Command` section directly, the result is identical: success but no rows affected when checking afterwards.

I have recreated the SP and the job, thinking I did something wrong. I have also changed the job owner to different accounts (from my own all the way to admin) thinking it had something to do with rights - the job history consistently reports success across the board.

What am I doing wrong or what am I not seeing?

Comment: For starters, I'd modify your SP to issue a SELECT with your WHERE clause before the UPDATE and PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@@ROWCOUNT) to verify that rows actually satisfy your WHERE condition.  Also, make sure your job step is pointing to the correct database.

Comment: Hi @ScottHodgin. It says 1, which is exactly the number of rows it should be. `Executed as user: [username here]. 1 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0).  The step succeeded.`

Comment: I'd build in a CASE and first `select @iCntMembers = count(*) FROM Members m WHERE m.BirthDate IS NULL AND m.MemberNumber IS NOT NULL AND m.MemberStatus IN (1,2)` to see if you have any results returned.

Comment: Is it T-SQL step? Under what account is it executig? Try to execute the code impersonating that login, maybe it really does nothing. Because you have date/time manipulations that can be language dependent (you didn't post here your udf code), and different logins can have different default language

Comment: ...you require some form of verification that records exist, because the UPDATE is always going to succeed with that WHERE statement. It either Updates records or doesn't, which will always result in job_status = success.

Comment: Does the job target the correct database?

Comment: It might help to post the actual code from your job step, as well as the various configuration details for that step.

Comment: Running the SQL Server Profiler might help to find out what's going on. If it does, your self-answer explaining the issue (and, if not immediately obvious, mentioning the solution) would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started yesterday by profiling the job execution and found nothing of interest.

As it turns out, the devil was in calling `[MyOtherDatabase].dbo.fn_LocalTimeToUTC`.

For some reason (that is beyond me), there's some credentials checking going on (yes: in a time conversion function...) but if that fails, no error is returned - but also no result. Don't ask. I didn't write it.

Once I decided to skip the conversion everything worked flawlessly.

I'll be wanting those two days of my life back now.